# Error after updating gradle plugin version of Android Studio from 2.3.3 to 3.0.0

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

I've recently updated my Android Studio's Gradle plugin version from 2.3.3 to 3.0.0 and followed the instructions shown [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html)

The updated build.gradle (app) looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "demo.myProject.projectdemoversion"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 41
        versionName "2.26"
        aaptOptions.setProperty("cruncherEnabled", false)
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {

        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            zipAlignEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation project(':volley')
    implementation('com.github.worker8:tourguide:1.0.17-SNAPSHOT@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }


    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.1'
    implementation 'ch.acra:acra:4.9.0'
    implementation 'com.github.MKergall:osmbonuspack:6.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'
    implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:5.6.4'
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-android:1.7.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.11.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.11.0'
    implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
}
```

And my build.gradle (project) is as follows:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
            maven { 
                url "https://jitpack.io"
            }
        maven(){
            url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
        }
        google()
    }

}
```

But unfortunately it's still showing errors related to plugins. For example:

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class info.hoang8f.widget.FButton

Here is the layout file which contains the FButton element:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:fbutton="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="demo.myProject.projectdemoversion.activity.PhoneRegActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:src="@drawable/menu_image_360" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/firstreg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/regpadding">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/phoneheader"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:text="Register here"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/regtext"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
            android:id="@+id/userid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/user"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:hint="Write your name"
            app:met_baseColor="@color/white"
            app:met_floatingLabel="highlight"
            app:met_textColorHint="@color/white" />

        <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
            android:id="@+id/phone_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/phonereceiver"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:hint="ফোন নাম্বার"
            android:inputType="none"
            android:padding="5dp"
            app:met_baseColor="@color/white"
            app:met_floatingLabel="normal"
            app:met_textColorHint="@color/white" />

        <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton

            android:id="@+id/submittoserver"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/regsubbtnsize"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/regsubbtn"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/regsubbtn"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/regsubbtn"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/regsubbtn"
            android:text="Submit"
            android:textColor="@color/colorSecondaryText"
            android:textSize="@dimen/offercounterbtn"
            fbutton:buttonColor="@color/colorAccent"
            fbutton:shadowColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            fbutton:shadowEnabled="true"
            fbutton:shadowHeight="5dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/secondreg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/regpadding"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|top"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:text="Welcome"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/regtext"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hellonaame"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|top"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:text="Register"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/regtext"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Any help/suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: try removing your library dependency..clean and rebuilt you project and then try adding the library again...

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Android Geek. But still it's not working :(

Comment: If you don't get any solution then you should try 2.3.3 gradle because the library may not be compatible for the latest gradle 3.0.0.

Comment: check for gradle compatibility and try "Invalidate cache and restart" Hope it will work.